# Magento: creating link to category with multiple languages

Tags: php, magento, url, hyperlink, translation

I've created a button on multiple categories to a specific category and made sure it's not visible on that category itself. See code below:

```
<?php
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
    $category_id = $category->getId();
    if(!($category_id == 123)):
    $category_url = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(123)->getUrl();
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category_url; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View specific category') ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works perfectly on the Dutch side of the webshop, but on the English side it logically links to the Dutch page.

What do I need to change to make it recognize it's on the English side and link to the English category?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$category_url = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")
          ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
          ->load(123)
          ->getUrl();
```